# What type of mail configuration to choose for an internal server in configuration mode of postfix

Tags: linux, postfix-mta

I'm in the middle of a process to reconfigure postfix to enable cron job to send automatic email notification to users.
like

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix

I got the following traceback:-
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
length() used on @choices (did you mean "scalar(@choices)"?) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Element/Teletype/Select.pm line 48, <GEN1> line 5.
length() used on @choices (did you mean "scalar(@choices)"?) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Element/Teletype/Select.pm line 63, <GEN1> line 5.
Postfix Configuration
---------------------

Please select the mail server configuration type that best meets your needs.

 No configuration:
  Should be chosen to leave the current configuration unchanged.
 Internet site:
[More] 

  Mail is sent and received directly using SMTP.
 Internet with smarthost:
  Mail is received directly using SMTP or by running a utility such
  as fetchmail. Outgoing mail is sent using a smarthost.
 Satellite system:
  All mail is sent to another machine, called a 'smarthost', for delivery.
 Local only:
  The only delivered mail is the mail for local users. There is no network.
[More] 


  1. No configuration  2. Internet Site  3. Internet with smarthost  4. Satellite system  5. Local only

General type of mail configuration: 

General type of mail configuration: 

General type of mail configuration: 5


The "mail name" is the domain name used to "qualify" _ALL_ mail addresses without a domain name. This includes mail to and from <root>: please do not make
your machine send out mail from root@example.org unless root@example.org has told you to.

This name will also be used by other programs. It should be the single, fully qualified domain name (FQDN).

Thus, if a mail address on the local host is foo@example.org, the correct value for this option would be example.org.
[More] 


System mail name:
```

In the above I have choosen 5.local host option as random, Its asking for mail name and I'm not pretty sure about the mail name. Could anyone suggest a way to find mail name.

Answer (score 0):

You're not being asked to find the mail name - you're being asked to assign a mail name. Also - local mail only, so only users with accounts on that server will receive mail. If you intend to send it outside your server (like to gmail) you will have to set it up as an Internet site.

Comment: If I have a work internal server like smtp.ABCDinternal.com. Which type of mail configuration shall i  choose ?

Comment: The problem with the question is only those familiar with the debconf wrapper to postfix setup can answer. `postfix` configuration is controlled by the file `main.cf` (and `master.cf`). You control who will get mail at your server with `mydestination` and who can send (relay) mail with `mynetworks`. If you have further information on what your 1,2,3,4,5 mean, I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: set it up as in internet site - you will be sending email to an internal internet.